# How to get a 'select-option' area updated automatically with the values from the database..?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want a "select-option" where the option values will be updated automatically. What i mean is
i want some specific values in the database to be put in the select-option area whenever it is 
updated in the database like when a user is registered in the database then i want his/her registration number to be updated in the "option-select" area the same time.How do i do it. I am coding in java/jsp/servlet.

Comment: how far have you come?

Comment: I have been searching for the solution but haven't got any. I also find it difficult to describe my question to the point. May be i will go for some other option if i can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if i get the right point in your question, but the key there is to use js-->java-->js

```
@RequestMapping("/url/loadData")
@ResponseBody
 public String loadData()
            throws Exception {
        JSONSerializer s = new JSONSerializer();
        return s.serialize(classService.getData());   //method to find the parsing of data from db
    }
```

call the mapping in js

```
 function loadDbData() {
    $.ajaxUtility({
        url : '/url/loadData.htm',
        showErrorPrompt : true,
        showInfoPrompt : false,
        success : function(data, xhr, s) {
            dataFromDB = data;
            $(dataFromDB).each(function(index, value){

                $("#myDropdownbox").empty();
                $("#myDropdownbox").append(generateEachData(value));

            });

        }
    });
 }

function generateEachData(dataItems){
    html = '<option>'+dataItems+'</option>';
    return html;
}
```

just call the loadDbData() upon the event when you want to update or call the data from db.
Hope it will help :)